# checking stationarity of POSIXct formatted xts object

Tags: r

my Acf plot suggest that the series is not stationary but at the same time Augmented Dickey Fuller test for stationarity gives the result that the series is stationary. How can this happen possibly?
[acfplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nwaJ.png)
[adftest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrA3Z.png)